# usage of smart pointers when automating visual studio

Tags: c++

I am using below code to manipulate visual studio.

Everything worked fine except that smart pointers did not release properly before function exit: it threw exception upon release.:exception 0xc0000005, access violation when write to 0xfeeefeee.

the running stop at the bold part below.

```
public:
    typedef T _PtrClass;
    ~CComPtrBase() throw()
    {
        if (p)
            p->Release();
    }
```

Could any one give me some hint?

```
int myAutomateVS()
{

    CoInitialize(NULL);

    CComPtr<IRunningObjectTable> pTable=NULL;
    GetRunningObjectTable(0, &pTable);

    CComPtr<IEnumMoniker> pEnumMoniker=NULL;;
    pTable->EnumRunning(&pEnumMoniker);

    CComPtr<IMoniker> pMoniker=NULL;
    ULONG nMoniker=0;

    CComPtr<IUnknown> pRunningObj=NULL;
    while(pEnumMoniker->Next(1, &pMoniker, &nMoniker) == S_OK)
    {
        CComPtr<IBindCtx> pCtx=NULL;
        CreateBindCtx(0, &pCtx);

        LPOLESTR pwszName;
        pMoniker->GetDisplayName(pCtx, NULL, &pwszName);


        pTable->GetObject(pMoniker, &pRunningObj);

        if(_tcsstr(pwszName, L"VisualStudio.DTE.8") != NULL)
            break;
    }
    CComPtr<EnvDTE::_DTE> pDTE;
    pDTE = pRunningObj;

    CComPtr<EnvDTE::_Solution> solution;
    pDTE->get_Solution(&solution);
    CComBSTR fullName;
    solution->get_FullName(&fullName);

    CoUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: which exception is thrown?

Comment: the exception was: 0xc0000005, access violation writing to 0xfeeefeee.

Comment: Where are your copy constructors and assignment operators?

Comment: You fell victim to one of the classic blunders - you call `CoUninitialize` while `CComPtr` objects holding interface pointers are still in scope. They will call `Release()` on their underlying dumb pointers at the closing brace - but that's illegal after `CoUninitialize`

Comment: `pTable->GetObject(pMoniker, &pRunningObj);` This leaks - the interface pointer currently held by `pRunningObj` is overwritten and never released.

Comment: `pDTE = pRunningObj;` Are you sure this compiles? I don't believe it should, unless `pDTE` is in reality a `CComQIPtr`.

Comment: Igor, thank you so much. The pDFE = pRunningObj really compileled and ran. I am not sure why.